# What sort of tree

Tags: identification

[image][image]We have acquired a very sick tree due to lack of water, but it is now recovering and has new growth.  Unfortunately we have no idea what it is and internet research has revealed little.  Can anyone identify.

The new leaves have red margins when first uncurling and fine serrated edges.  I assume the leaves will turn green as they mature.  They are glossy and quite thick.[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably a Camellia, but hard to be sure at this stage

Comment: I agree, Bamboo.  Camellias and sooty mold!  Never met a Camellia that didn't have sooty mold.

Comment: Interesting, I think it may not be a camellia. I had to go look at my 12 sasanquas  and 11 Japonicas  as a reminder; The  tiny serrations on the leaf margin are just like Japonica , however the new growth buds on Camellias are short ,fat and green - not elongated and reddish like the picture. And apparently the gulf coast climate does not support sooty mold as I have never seen it on a camellia ( I hate to say something different from @ storm). We do have a problem with a tiny white  fuzzy scale. Where is this plant growing ?

Comment: The reddish tint to the new leaf bud is somewhat concerning - it may be indicative of Camellia Leaf Gall. This plant doesn't look like it suffered drought, but has other problems - I'm not seeing sooty mold anywhere, but there is leaf spot... what part of the world are you in?

Comment: Thank you Bamboo and blacksmith37.  The plant is on the east coast of Lincolnshire in the UK.  It  was totally pot bound, it came out of the pot in a solid lump no loose soil.  It looked as if it had not been watered in months ,bone dry.  We have given it buckets of water.  I have added two more pictures for info.   I have three camellias whose leaves are much much bigger and a very dark green but they do not have a single trunk like this one.  They have three or four branches all coming from the ground.

Comment: Does anyone think it might be Camelia sinensis?